# Get TextBox focus in WPF app from plugins in separate process

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, system.addin

We are using the System.AddIn structure for creating an application for hosting apps. What we would like is to hook up to the event that a TextBox gets focus in these separate apps.

How can we do that?

I know the processes, so I can access those and maybe listen on the message pump? But how? What messages to listen for and how to determine if that control getting focus is actually a TextBox (WPF type)?

Hope for your help!

Comment: Check that e.OriginalSource is TextBox.

Comment: I don't have access to the TextBox instance, so I can't listen to your above event, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it in an "out of the box" way.

A solution could be create a duplex WCF service exposed by all wpf processes.

Then the client can connect to the services and use a Register method to listen to events.

The service implementation will then dispatch events to the registered clients.
It takes some time but I think it is the only way.

Comment: I would like to avoid putting the responsibility on the app developer.

Answer (score 0):

For now we are investigating the possibility of using the EventManager.RegisterClassHandler method, to register in the separate appdomain and handle the implementation in the adapter for each developer.